# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in index.blade.php

Tags: php, sql, laravel

**I have two tables departments and employees.I want to list departments or employees.The department is okay but when i want to see the employees it gives me this error.I have tried some solutions but it didnt help me ,it still shows this error**

this is employees\index.blade.php

```
----
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Department</td>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($employees as $employee)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{  $employee->department->name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
---
```

this is web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
//Route::get('login/github', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToGithub');
//Route::get('login/github/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleGithubCallback');
Route::resource('departments', 'DepartmentsController');
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

departments/index.blade.php

```
...
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($departments as $department)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $department->name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
...
```

EmployeesController

```
   public function index()
    {
        $employees = \App\Employee::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        return view('employees.index')->with('employees', $employees);
    }
```

DepartmentsController

```
    public function index()
    {
        $departments = \App\Department::all();
        $departments = \App\Department::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        $departments = \App\Department::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('departments.index')->with('departments', $departments);
    }
```

The error im getting is
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\test2\resources\views\employees\index.blade.php)

If i do   return \App\Employee::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10); i get this

```
{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":2,"name":"Laura","department":""},{"id":1,"name":"Ana","department":""}],"first_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/Laravel\/test2\/public\/employees?page=1","from":1,"last_page":1,"last_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/Laravel\/test2\/public\/employees?page=1","next_page_url":null,"path":"http:\/\/localhost\/Laravel\/test2\/public\/employees","per_page":10,"prev_page_url":null,"to":2,"total":2}
```

Comment: cool, this looks good, can you do `\App\Employee::with('department')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);`

Comment: it gives me this error:    lluminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [department] on model [App\Employee].

Comment: ok, so it means there is no relationship between `department` and `employee`, have you setup foreign key between these tables?

Comment: thank you very much i was trying to see it and this was the problem.Its solved.I didnt add  the relationship thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will assume that the relationship is one department has many employees. This is how you set up your model relationships.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
}
```

This is how you can set up the relationship from DB part.(if you did not have it properly)

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->bigInteger('department_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('department_id')
          ->references('id')->on('departments')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#307 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Employee {#308 ▶}
    1 => App\Employee {#309 ▶}
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

u can use {{  $employee->department->name ?? "" }} to eradicate this error.